# What is the ship called that transports Yoda and the clones into the arena in Episode II?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, attack-of-the-clones

It is open on the sides and Yoda looks out of it and stands in front of clones. They are coming to rescue Anakin, Obi-Wan and Padmé.

Comment: "Yaddle's Alimony"

Answer (score 13):

I believe you're talking about the scene where the heroes are rescued from a mass attack of battle droids in the arena; those ships are "[Low Altitude Assault Transports/infantry](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport/infantry)"

[image: Front view of LAAT]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp4O4.jpg - From the *Star Wars - Complete Visual Dictionary*

Comment: More commonly known as the "Republic Gunship" - based on OP's username, they might be looking for a model of it.

Comment: @MiloP - They get a really nice double-page spread in the *Attack of the Clones: Incredible Cross-Sections* book; https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4iul.jpg

Comment: @MiloP Or the "Larty", in GAR parlance.

Answer (score 7):

As per Milo P's comment, it is commonly known as "Republic Gunship", while also going by the name "Low Altitude Assault Transport/infantry (LAATi)".

Based on your username, here are some LEGO models:

- https://brickset.com/sets/75309-1/Republic-Gunship
  [image: Republic Gunship UCS Lego model]
- https://brickset.com/sets/75021-1/Republic-Gunship
  [image: Republic Gunship Lego model]
- https://brickset.com/sets/75076-1/Republic-Gunship-Microfighter
  [image: Republic Gunship Microfighter Lego model]